# java program - low CPU utilization

Tags: java

I wrote a java program processing/parsing/persisting emails from SMTP server
I see that the CPU utilization is very low,
What set the amount of CPU my Java program can use?
How to increase the CPU utilization? say I would like it to use 100% of the physical CPU while its running.
I understand that it might be waiting on resources, but while an email is being parsed why isn't there a 100% spike in CPU Usage?

[image: low cpu]
[image]

Comment: You could use a thread to send mails and create another to work meanwhile.

Comment: there is a high probability most of the time your program is waiting for network.

Comment: if its waiting for network why isn't there  100% spike in CPU Usage while its processing/

Comment: to 100% utilize CPU. you basically need to feed CPU with N threads, if your CPU has N cores and each of those threads at given time should be executing some computational work.

Comment: @JigarJoshi [i5-6300U](https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/products/processors/core/core-vpro/i5-6300u.html) has 2 cores. So why not 50% at least?

Comment: Is there really any *computational* work available for each tick of CPU at a given time.

Comment: We have no idea what your code is doing, since you didn't post any code nor any input. My guess is that the task your program is doing is so simple and fast that it doesn't last long enough to cause a spike in the CPU consumption chart, which probably polls the CPU consumption every second or so. A second is a huge amount of time for a fast CPU. You can do a whole lot of things in well under 1 second.

Comment: Who says there *isn't* 100% CPU utilization for a millisecond or two out of each second while the program parses emails?  Each point in your utilization graph shows average utilization over a smallish window.  You need to maintain full usage over the whole window to see the usage go all the way up to 100%.